# Calculating dynamically sum in ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<body ng-controller="testeCtrl">
  <img src="http://adsim.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/adsim_logo_cores_2x.png" alt="#" class="logo">
  <div class="jumbotron barraPrincipal" ng-app="teste">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">
          <th>
            <select class="logo form-control" ng-model="refrigerante" ng-options="refrige as (refrige.nome+' '+refrige.quantidade) for refrige in refri">
              <option value="">
                <h4>Selecione o refrigerante</h4></option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" min="1" placeholder="Informe a quantidade" ng-model="quantidade"></input>
          </th>
          <th>
            <h4>Valor Unitário: {{refrigerante.preco | currency:'R$' }}</h4>
          </th>

          <th>
            <h4 ng-show="refrigerante != null && quantidade > 0 && quantidade != 0" ng-model="i.fields[$index].item_count" name="item_count">Valor dos produtos: {{va = quantidade*refrigerante.preco | currency:'R$'}} </h4></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <!-- total value of refrigerante.preco*quantidade here -->
          <td>Valor total <span> </span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow does generally expect posts to be in English. Try [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum something, ng-repeat will probably not help. You can define a filter or call a function on the scope like this in the html: {{calculateSum()}}

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a lot of semantic errors in your HTML, one of them is in the `<input>` **tag**. It's a *self-closing* tag, so you don't need close it. Also, you are trying to get the total value **outside** the `ngRepeat`...

To achieve what you want just create a `function` in your **controller**, as below:

```
$scope.total = function(refrigerante, quantidade) {
  return refrigerante.preco * quantidade;    
}
```

Then call it in your **view**:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">
  ...
  <td ng-bind="'Valor total ' + total()"></td>
  <!-- Or -->
  <td>Valor total {{total()}}</td>
</tr>
```